# d3 enter and append not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 brush to update my graph.. When I update the graph when the filter values change the values are not being updated properly. When I am trying to debug my `circles` variables shows something like `[Arr[3] ,Arr[2], Arr[1]]` and `circles.enter() = [Arr[3] ,Arr[2], Arr[1]]` and `circles.exit() = [Arr0 ,Arr0, Arr0]`. But when `circles.enter.append()` is run only the first value in the circle is added to the graph.

```
var create_circles = function(data, color, filter_arr) {
    data = [
        {
            key: "3003",
            values: [
                {
                    key: "0R",
                    values: [
                        {a: '0r1'},
                        {a: '0r2'},
                        {a: '0r3'}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    key: "0G",
                    values: [
                        {a: '0g1'},
                        {a: '0g2'},
                        {a: '0g3'}
                    ]

                }
            ]
        },
        {
            key: "3004",
            values: [
                {
                    key: "0R",
                    values: [
                        {a: '04r1'},
                        {a: '04r2'},
                        {a: '04r3'},
                        {a: '04r4'}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    key: "0G",
                    values: [
                        {a: '04g1'},
                        {a: '04g2'}
                    ]

                }
            ]
        }

    ];
    var LRGroups = d3.selectAll("svg .L, svg .R")
        .data(data);

    var LxRxGroups = LRGroups.selectAll("g").data(function(d){
          return d.values;
        });

    var circles = LxRxGroups.selectAll('circle')
        .data(function(d) {
            if(filter_arr[0] < 50)
                return [d.values[1]]
            else
                return d.values
        },  function(d) {
            console.log(d)
            return d;

        })
    circles.enter().append("circle").attr("r", function(d) {
        console.log(d.a);
        return 1;
    })
    .attr("cx", 1)
    .attr("cy", 1);

    circles.exit().remove();
}
```

I have some sample data inside to test it out. If i run the function using `create_cicles(1,2,[50,60])` I have the below log data..

```
{a: "0r1"}
{a: "0r2"}
{a: "0r3"}
{a: "0g1"}
{a: "0g2"}
{a: "0g3"}
{a: "04r1"}
{a: "04r2"}
{a: "04r3"}
{a: "04r4"}
{a: "04g1"}
{a: "04g2"}

Log from inside append
0r1
0g1
04r1
04g1
```

The svg structure is created by using same data but stays same between updates.

```
<svg width="1000" height="800">
    <g transform="translate(80,100)">
        <g class="L">
            <g class="L1"></g>
            <g class="L2"></g>
        </g>
        <g class="R">
            <g class="R1"></g>
            <g class="R2"></g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I have the dataset as shown in the example above but bigger, so once the page loads I loop over the array to create a svg bare format as above. After that if I call `create_circles(1,1, [50, 60])`, I expect that all values in the dataset above be created, but I find that only one element is created for each array ie. `or1, og1, o4r1, o4g1`. So I am unable to understand the reason behind this, because the `circles` variable shows that it contains `[3,3,4,2]` elements and `circles.enter()` also shows the same no and `circles.exit()` showing `[0,0,0,0]`. This should then mean that `3+3+4+2=12` elements are appended to the svg, but only 4 are added. Hope this makes sense.. I have attached the entire code [here](http://codepad.co/s/d7c240). The `create_circles` above is slightly modified of the one in the file so that it is easier to debug.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking -- how are you updating and what do you expect to happen? Could you provide a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have added some additional info, let me know if that makes sense.. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Could you provide a *complete* example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have made a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9u9u6yL7/3/

Comment: Hmm, nothing obviously wrong to me. The whole thing is quite complicated though because of your triple-nested selection. I would try to narrow it down to a minimal example.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff If you slide the brush below 50, you see 4 points that is fine, but If you go above 50 if expect all points to be shown ie. 12. But i am getting only 4 points.  https://jsfiddle.net/9u9u6yL7/4/

Comment: Sure, but as I've said, it's not obvious to me where the problem is.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thank you.. will look into it